Reuse results of random generation function as "const"
Newbie question here,
For Cypress test of a  web project, I generated a random name for an item creation. I want to "store" the resultat as "const" in order to check that folder is created.
Here is my function:
    function testFolderName() {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-_"

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      return text;
    }

In the next cy.get I want to check the folder list contains a folder with random folder name that have been generated. But I have no idea where to start with.
